# Why do I get imprecise results from an inner product calculation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below is used to calculate the inner product of two vectors, but sometimes it returns wrong values and I don't know why. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Specifically for these inputs: [-2.328, -7.284, -1.214] and [-1.821, 1.072, -2.94]

```
reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates)])
```

Comment: Why not just: `sum(x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates, v.coordinates))`. Give an example of the dataset that gives wrong results.

Comment: You should take a look at [`np.inner`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html).

Comment: that works the same. You know both of them return wrong answers when I use them to calculate the inner product of the vectors: [-2.328, -7.284, -1.214] and [-1.821, 1.072, -2.94] @MosesKoledoye

Comment: thank you, but I was trying to implement this method myself as a part of linear algebra course at udacity.com @Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this is a rounding error. Using the vectors in your example:

```
a = [-2.328, -7.284, -1.214]
b = [-1.821, 1.072, -2.94]
c = reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [x*y for x,y in zip(a, b)])
print(c)
```

will give `-1.3322676295501878e-15` while the real result should be `0`. For comparison the numpy function `np.inner(a,b)` will give a very similar result; `-1.33226762955e-15`.

The error is due to that any number that can't be built from exact powers of two can't be represented exactly as a floating point number and needs to be approximated. For more in-depth information you can read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).